# update or refresh WPF app to save Textbox input

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF app i have multiple textboxes or comboboxes and so on. The user can enter input. All input data is binded to the viewmodel for further functionality in my app.

The Problem here is that the last Form which was edited by the user, for example a Textbox, does not override the data in the  viewmodel until you press somewhere else in the GUI, effectively "leaving" the textbox. But I can't guarantee that the user does this everytime before pressing the button for the next app functionality which uses the data. So sometimes this last change is not taken into account.

Is there some way to make the app "refresh" or do this unfocus of these forms itself?

Comment: I would advise you to look into the `OnTextChanged` or better even `LostKeyboardFocus` Events.

Comment: Try setting the property `UpdateSourceTrigger` on the binding to the value `PropertyChanged`. This should help, because the docs state for the `Text` property of the `TextBox` [_"When used in data-binding scenarios, this property uses the default update behavior of UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus."_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.text?view=netcore-3.1#remarks)

Comment: is there a universal way to do this? because i have about 200 of these data bindings, and  each of these could be the last one edited by the user.

Comment: @Arne_22 take a look at [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ea88bec4-8397-415f-adf7-f3ccd5f3b9cb/how-to-change-binding-updatesourcetrigger-default?forum=wpf)  for a possible solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default [`UpdateSourceTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger?view=netcore-3.1) is [`LostFocus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger?view=netcore-3.1#fields) for [performance and usability reasons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger?view=netcore-3.1).

> Updating after every keystroke can diminish performance and it denies the user the usual opportunity to backspace and fix typing errors before committing to the new value. Therefore, the default UpdateSourceTrigger value of the Text property is LostFocus and not PropertyChanged.

Change it to [`PropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger?view=netcore-3.1#fields) in each binding, so the source is updated on each keystroke.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding YourProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: This works as intended. Is there a way to do it for all of the bindings instead of assigning the attribute for each manually?

Comment: The [linked thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ea88bec4-8397-415f-adf7-f3ccd5f3b9cb/how-to-change-binding-updatesourcetrigger-default?forum=wpf) by @Ackdari shows a way to do this. Personally, I think that it is more complex to do so and does not offer much benefit over assigning the update trigger in the binding directly. However, both approaches have advantages and disadvantages, so it might be a matter of taste to choose between them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do many of these I'dr recommend creating a class that you call on every `OnTextChanged` event.
so that your page refreshes every keystroke.